# Smart data gathering from Collection of DTO

Tags: java, collections, java-7

Let's assume that we have a List of ExampleDTO that contains some fields, among others "name" field. Everytime I want to get a list of proper fields, in this case names, I write code as below:

```
private List<String> getNames(List<ExampleDTO> exampleDTOs) {
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (ExampleDTO exampleDTO : exampleDTOs)
        names.add(exampleDTO.getName());
    return names;
}
```

...but I also noticed that this kind of code is repeating over and over again.

And the question is: **Is there any smart method that would help me reduce amount of redundant code produced?**

**EDIT:**

I'm using `Java7` for my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 7 you can use Guava's [`FluentIterable`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) and [`Function`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html):

```
List<ExampleDTO> exampleDTOs = ...;
List<String> names = FluentIterable.from(exampleDTOs)
   .transform(new Function<ExampleDTO, String>() {
       @Override
       public String apply(ExampleDTO dto) {
           return dto.getName();
       }
   })
   .toList();
```

Note that, although the whole loop is expressed as a single expression, **the performance is significantly worse than a loop, and it's very arguable if this is more readable.**

**I would stick to a simple loop until the upgrade to Java 8.**

In one of the projects, I used to mark all such loops with special comments, so that all these places were easy to find when the upgrade to Java 8 was performed.

---

With Java 8 you could use Streams API:

```
List<ExampleDTO> exampleDTOs = ...;
List<String> names = exampleDTOs.stream()
    .map(dto -> dto.getName())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It could get even shorter if you don't necessarily need the *list* of names — in this case the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` part could be removed.

For example, you can iterate over the list of names directly on the stream as follows:

```
exampleDTOs.stream()
    .map(dto -> dto.getName())
    .forEach(name -> System.out.println(name));
```

This would just print all the names, but you can replace the `System.out.println(name)` with anything else.

Comment: Okay, I have plans to upgrade to Java 8 version in the near future so I accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In java 8 you have a new interface called `Function` allowing you to map a value to get something else, the idea here would be to implement the same logic with Java 7.

So the function interface would be:

```
public interface Function<T, R> {

    /**
     * Applies this function to the given argument.
     * @param t the function argument
     * @return the function result
     */
    R apply(T t);
}
```

and your method could be something like that:

```
private <R> List<R> getValues(List<ExampleDTO> exampleDTOs, Function<ExampleDTO, R> function) {
    List<R> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ExampleDTO exampleDTO : exampleDTOs)
        values.add(function.apply(exampleDTO));
    return values;
}
```

In your case you could use a private static final variable to define your function as an anonymous class, like this:

```
private static final Function<ExampleDTO, String> BY_NAME = new Function<ExampleDTO, String>() {
    public String apply(ExampleDTO e) {
        return e.getName();
    }
}
```

Then calls `getValues(exampleDTOs, BY_NAME)`